# Problem with base 64 encoding and decoding

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on an ethernet wrapper (c#) to communicate with some looms.
The looms communication is managed via custom protocol.

The problem is that the data part(of ethernet wrapper) is encoded using the 64 base encoding protocol.
The documentation says that the string "10/1/3" after the base64 encoding will results in "CgED".

Any idea on how is it possibile to get that "CgED" from "10/1/3"?

Because if i try to convert "10/1/3" the result is "MTAvMS8z".

Comment: Please review the "How to ask a question" thread. 

[ask] It would be nice with: what you have already tried, expected input, corresponding expected output, what kind of error message you might have received, and enough code to verify and validate your example.

Comment: You can find it here: [ask].

Comment: @MortenBork - Just put `[ask]` in your comment to have the link automagically inserted when you hit enter.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the tip. I will do so from now on ;)

Comment: You are right, "CgED" is not the base64 encoding of "10/1/3". Don't know which protocol you are using. But either the docs are wrong or they messed up the implementation.